# android -custom dialog with close button half outside

Tags: android, dialog, popup, android-dialogfragment

I want to create DialogFragment like shown in screen, the problem is to create close button outside of the dialog.

[image: Close button overflow outside of popup]

Comment: which is the code you're using?

Answer (score 6):

Use this code for making custom dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:background="#111111" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents into a separate layout so that the Button and the contents layout are siblings in another layout, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout               //Contents, the list etc.
        android:padding="20dp"
        />   
    <Button                       //Your close Button
        android:alignParentTop="true"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        />           
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now give the contents layout a `android:padding`, lets say 20dp. At the same time, give the Button `android:alignParentTop` and `android:alignParentRight`.

This should work the way you want it to